Problems to highlight text with a chart compontent (component is the events type) with splunk cloud 9.2
I have a dashboard made in Splunk Cloud 9.2, where I am using an "events" type graph in which I get information by executing an SPL query, however, I would like to highlight a particular text and I am not able to achieve it because the "highlight" command does not work for this component, it is trying everything but it cannot do it.
The response text is the following:
"2024-11-15T05:30:12:312 [sid:12345 | tn:1234] ERROR TestText => This is a test"
And here are some of the ways I tried to highlight the text:
Alternative 1

index="mngd_k8s" cluster_name="cluster_test"  "TestText =>"
| eval _raw = if(match(_raw, "TestText =>\\s*$"), replace(_raw, "TestText =>\\s*$", ""), _raw)
| highlight ERROR
| table _raw

Alternative 2

index="mngd_k8s" cluster_name="cluster_test"  "TestText =>"
| eval _raw = if(match(_raw, "TestText =>\\s*$"), replace(_raw, "TestText =>\\s*$", ""), _raw)
| eval highlighted=_raw
| highlight term="ERROR"
| table highlighted


Alternative 3

index="mngd_k8s" cluster_name="cluster_test"  "TestText =>"
| eval _raw = if(match(_raw, "TestText =>\\s*$"), replace(_raw, "TestText =>\\s*$", ""), _raw)
| eval _raw=replace(_raw, "ERROR:", "<span class='highlight-error'>ERROR</span>")
| table _raw

"options": {
        "highlight": [
            {
                "field": "_raw",
                "condition": "like(_raw, 'ERROR')",
                "style":{
                    "backgroundColor": "yellow",
                    "fontWeight": "bold"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

I don't know if anyone knows of any alternatives I can use to achieve this?
I neet to highlight the "ERROR" word whith SPL in splunk cloud 9.2
